# jQuery: Get value of url in load() function

Tags: jquery

I'm using a library which has already defined an onclick event handler on a hyperlink eg:

```
&lt;a onclick="$('#myDiv').load('/?__=634285190817664832&amp;sort=Id&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1 #myDiv');" href="#">1&lt;/a>
```

How can I get the value of the 'url' parameter?

Comment: Regex on what exactly? The DOM? I can access the onclick attribute of the href, and I get: 

function onclick(event) {
    $("#grid").load("/?page=3&__=634285215353428198 #grid");
}

Comment: OK - Regex on the returned value of the onclick attribute, taking into account TJ Crowders warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

...after tobyodavies pointed out (in the nicest of ways) that I was being thick. If you explicitly retrieve the *attribute*, rather than the reflected property, we'll get back the string from the DOM, not a function, and so don't have to worry about function decompilation (see notes below). The remainder of the below is a bit paranoid (because I originally was working from function decompilation), but still:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var link, onclick, url, index;

  link = $('#theLink')[0];
  // IMPORTANT: Getting the *attribute* here, not the reflected property.
  // jQuery's `attr` function will give you the property, so go direct.
  onclick = link.getAttribute("onclick");
  display("onclick = " + onclick);
  index = onclick.indexOf("load('");
  if (index < 0) {
    url = "(unknown)";
  }
  else {
    url = onclick.substring(index + 6);
    index = url.indexOf("');");
    if (index > 0) {
      url = url.substring(0, index);
    }
  }
  display("url = " + url);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arolo4/2)

### Original Answer

Note that **here there be dragons**. The value of the `onclick` reflected property by the time you're accessing it in the DOM is a function object on most browsers, and so you'll have to use `Function#toString`, which has never been standardized and some mobile browsers are known to just return "[object Function]". Most desktop browsers return a decompiled version of the event handler, but that can change at any time.

But now you're aware of the dragons, you *can* get it that way. Here's a somewhat paranoid approach:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var link, onclick, url, index;

  link = $('#theLink')[0];
  onclick = "" + link.onclick;
  display("onclick = " + onclick);
  index = onclick.indexOf("load('");
  if (index < 0) {
    url = "(unknown)";
  }
  else {
    url = onclick.substring(index + 6);
    index = url.indexOf("');");
    if (index > 0) {
      url = url.substring(0, index);
    }
  }
  display("url = " + url);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arolo4)

Comment: I'm not bothered about the dragons, and thanks for the effort you put in.

Comment: why not use the attribute nodes in the DOM - no parsing the string representation of the function?

Comment: @tobyodavies: Gah, I keep forgetting that the attribute is still there and may have a *different* (more useful!) value than the reflected property. Nice one. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://google.de" onclick="alert(this.href);">Link</a>
```

Or did you mean this?

```
$(function() {
    var a = $('#link').attr('onclick');
    var l = (a+"").split("'");
    alert(l[3]);
});
```

You can also replace the "$" object (Beware! This is solution is working in chome, but I did not do too much testing...)

```
$(function() {
    var a = $('#link').attr('onclick');
    var temp = $;

    // Override jQuery
    $ = function (t) {
        var s = new Object;
        s.load = function(url) { alert(url); }; 
        return s
    }
    a();

    // ...and back again
    $ = temp;

    // Is jQuery still working?
    alert($('#link').text());
});
```

Comment: jQuery abuse alert! `alert($(this).attr('href'));` => `alert(this.href);` ;-) More seriously, though, not seeing how this answers the OP's question about extracting the URL from the `load` call...

Comment: The href value is effectively hardcoded as #. That's not what I want. I want the value of the url parameter in the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute nodes to get the un-parsed version, then use a regex to extract the URL.

```
link.attributes.getNamedItem('onclick').value.match(/someRegex/)
```

Comment: That will get the `href` of the link, though, not the URL that the `load` function in the handler is using.